# Does a version of a master template need to be on every server that a database resides on if only a design element is inheriting from it?

Tags: lotus-notes, teamstudio-unplugged

Scenario: We have four databases that are setup to inherit from a master template and they in turn have individual design elements that inherit from a different master template via template name added in the field shown in image.

It has always been my understanding that in order for the individual design elements in the database to inherit any changes a version of the master template must also be on all servers where the database resides so that the nightly server process will make updates to the design element(s).

Is this true?  Does this change when creating a build using Teamstudio CIAO Builds/Promotions?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIAO! / Build Manager uses the IBM Domino API to perform a Design Refresh, therefore it does not need to wait for the nightly Design task to run.

CIAO! / Build Manager calls the Design Refresh API and passes the Target DB info and then name of the IBM Server where the template resides. Therefore for a full design refresh of a Target db the Template does not need to reside on the same server.

If you have indicated a Design Template for individual Design Elements within a Notes Application, then in this scenario the Master Template would need to reside on the IBM Domino server where the Notes Application also resides.  The CIAO! / Build Manager application does not include the capability of updating these individual Design Elements.

Answer (score 3):

If you want changes to any design elements to be automatically picked up from templates overnight - regardless of whether they inherit individually as in your screenshot, or inherit from the template named in the database properties - then one of the following must be true:

- If the database is replicated to multiple servers, then the templates must be on at least one of those servers; or
- If the database is only on one server, then the templates must be on that server.

So, if you have a few databases that are on one server each and not replicated, and they inherit from the same templates, then you'd need those templates on every server to get automatic overnight inheritance in every database.

However, there's no need to rely on automatic inheritance, as users with Designer access to affected databases can manually refresh designs from templates using the Notes or Designer client. If you do this, you can keep the templates on just one server regardless of how many servers have databases using those templates.

Note regarding template designs in any case, whether databases are automatically or manually refreshed: Best practice (as I understand it) is to have production template designs signed by a single user id created for the express purpose of signing designs, with a Domino policy in place to ensure that all users Execution Control Lists (ECLs) trust that signer, to prevent users from getting ECL alerts when using production applications.

My experience with Teamstudio CIAO isn't extensive, but I don't think it changes any of the above.

Comment: I hope someone with more extensive Teamstudio CIAO expereience than the two of us replies to this because our deployment team is thinking that when Teamstudio Build Manager is used to create a build of the databases template it picks up the changes made to the master template and then gets promoted to the higher environments.  We do follow the bast practice as  you mentioned and I understand only needing template on a single of the replica servers.